# Warning assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast . float findMeanLine(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]) , findMeanCol(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])

Tags: c, scope, return-type, function-definition, variable-length-array

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <stdbool.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    
    
    
    
    void fillPin2D(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
    void showPin2D(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
    float findMeanLine(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
    float findMeanCol(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
    void showPinDouble1D(int n,float avgLine[n]);
    int findDSum(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
    
    
    
    
    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        srand( time(NULL) );
        int n;
        printf ("give a number higher than five (5)\n\n");
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        while (n <= 5)
        {
            printf ("give a number higher than five (5)\n\n");
            scanf ("%d",&n);
        }
        printf("\n");
        int my2DArray[n][n];
        float avgLine[n],avgCol[n];
```

// filling array /////

```
        fillPin2D (n, my2DArray);
```

//showing array /////

```
        showPin2D(n, my2DArray);
        printf("\n\n");
```

// average per line /////

```
        avgLine[n] = findMeanLine(n, my2DArray);
```

//show average per line /////
showPinDouble1D(n,avgLine);

//average per Col /////

```
        avgCol[n] = findMeanCol(n ,my2DArray);
```

//Show average per Col /////

```
        showPinDouble1D(n,avgCol);
```

//add 2 diagonals /////

```
        int sumD;
        sumD = findDSum(n ,my2DArray);
        printf ("sumD = %d",sumD);
        
        return 0;   
    }
    
    void fillPin2D(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])
    {
        int row,col;
        for (row=0 ; row <n ; row++)
            for (col=0 ; col<n ; col++)
                my2DArray[row][col] = rand()%10 + 1;
    }
    void showPin2D(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])
    {
        int row,col;
        for (row=0 ; row <n ; row++)
        {
            for (col=0 ; col<n ; col++)
            {
                printf ("%d  ",my2DArray[row][col]);
            }
            printf ("\n");
        }
    }
    float findMeanLine(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])
    {
        int sumRow=0;
        int row,col;
        float avgLine[n];
        for (row=0; row <n ; row++)
        {
            sumRow=0;
            for (col=0 ; col < n ; col++)
            {
                printf("%lu\n", sizeof(my2DArray));
                printf("%d\n",my2DArray[row,col]);    
//checking value of my2DArray[row,col]

                sumRow+=my2DArray[row,col]; 
//[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast      
            }
            avgLine[row]=(float)sumRow/n;
        }
        return avgLine[n];
    }
    void showPinDouble1D(int n,float avgLine[])
    {
        printf("avg = ");
        int a;
        for (a=0 ; a < n ; a++)
        {
            printf(" %f ",avgLine[a]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    float findMeanCol(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])
    {
        int row,col;
        float avgCol[n];
        for (col=0 ; col < n ; col++)
        {
            int sumCol=0;
            for (row=0; row < n ; row++)
            {
                printf("%d\n",my2DArray[row,col]);
```

//checking value of my2DArray[row,col]
sumCol+=my2DArray[row,col];

//[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
}

```
            avgCol[col]=(float)sumCol/n;
        }
        return avgCol[n];
    }
    int findDSum(int n ,int my2DArray[][n])
    {
        int row,col,sumD=0;
        double avgCol[n];
        for (col=0 ; col < n ; col++)
        {
            int sumCol=0;
            for (row=0; row < n ; row++)
            {
                if (row==col)
                {
                    sumD+=my2DArray[row][col];
                }
                else if (n-row-1 == col)
                {
                    sumD+=my2DArray[row][col];
                }
            }
        }
        return sumD;
    }
```

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/))
 — the same idea by a different name.  Note the "minimal" and "short" parts of the descriptions — you have provided far more code than is necessary to reproduce the problem.  And your interpolated comments make it hard to see where the problem really is.

Comment: First: Read, understand and act on the comment made by @JonathanLeffler. But, looking through your code quickly, I see you sometimes use `my2DArray[row][col]` and other places have `my2DArray[row,col]`. Only the former is correct syntax.

Answer (score 3):

The both functions `findMeanLine` and `findMeanCol` are invalid.

It seems you are trying to return an array from the functions but the return type of the functions is `float` as for example

```
float findMeanLine(int n ,int my2DArray[][n]);
```

Also, you may not return a local array with automatic storage duration from a function because it will not be alive after exiting the function.

This statement

```
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(my2DArray));
```

does not make great sense because it always outputs the size of a pointer.

In this statement

```
printf("%d\n", my2DArray[row,col]);
```

In the expression `my2DArray[row,col]` there is used the comma operator in brackets. It seems you mean `my2DArray[row][col]`.

In this return statement

```
return avgLine[n];
```

you are trying to return a non-existent element of the array with the index n. The valid range of indices is `[0, n )`.

You should redeclare the functions like for example

```
void findMeanLine(int n, int my2DArray[][n], float avgLine[]);
```

where the third parameter will specify an array with `n` elements declared in the caller of the functions.

And the functions will be called like

```
findMeanLine(n, my2DArray, avgLine);
```

or

```
findMeanCol(n, my2DArray, avgCol);
```

P.S.

Looking at your code, I can presume that you think that you may assign one array to another like

```
avgCol[n] = findMeanCol(n, my2DArray);
```

However, arrays do not have the assignment operator. And moreover the expression `avgCol[n]` is a non-existent element of the array `avgCol`.